# MySQL SELECT calculation subject to stricter criteria than other SELECT fields--how?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Previously, the following query was limited based on work_category_id.  Turns out we need information from as subclass of another work_category_id, so now I'm limiting on job_code_id instead.  Job_code_id 29 is work_category_id 88, all other job_code_ids shown are work_category_id 36.

I need hours and performance for each of these job_code_ids, but specifically for the 'cases_per_hr' calculation, I only want to divide cases by all hours except those from job_code_id 29.  I tried a nested case when, but that didn't seem to make much sense.  Please help!

```
SELECT
d.user_id as 'employee_ID', 
round((sum(d.goal_hours)/sum(d.worked_hours)),2)*100 as 'performance', 
round(sum(d.goal_hours),2) as 'goal_hrs',
round(sum(d.worked_hours),2) as 'hrs_worked',
sum(d.cases) as 'total_cases_slctd', 
round(sum(d.cases)/sum(d.worked_hours),0) as 'cases_per_hr',
d.metric_dt

FROM
roster r,
prod_detail d

WHERE
d.process_level = r.process_level
and d.accounting_unit = r.accounting_unit
and d.job_code_id in ('29','322','304','303','302','305','181')
-- and d.work_category_id in('36')
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Please post sample data and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to exclude job_code_id = '29' from your cases_per_hr calculation, you could do the following.  It does use CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT  d.user_id as 'employee_ID', 
        round((sum(d.goal_hours)/sum(d.worked_hours)),2)*100 as 'performance', 
        round(sum(d.goal_hours),2) as 'goal_hrs',
        round(sum(d.worked_hours),2) as 'hrs_worked',
        sum(d.cases) as 'total_cases_slctd', 
        round(
              sum(CASE WHEN d.job_code_id <> '29' THEN d.cases ELSE 0 END) 
              /
              sum(CASE WHEN d.job_code_id <> '29' THEN d.worked_hours ELSE 0 END)
             ,0) as 'cases_per_hr',
        d.metric_dt

FROM    roster r,
        prod_detail d

WHERE
        d.process_level = r.process_level
        and d.accounting_unit = r.accounting_unit
        and d.job_code_id in ('29','322','304','303','302','305','181')
```